# Visual Studio C++ enum takes a long time to compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, enums

I have a dll with an enum (and many other things)

```
enum class KIT_API VoxelTypes : uint16_t
{
  ... about a hundred entries ...
    ModellingClay_00 = 65406,
... more entries ...
    ModellingClay_128,
    COUNT
};
```

The value of element COUNT is 65535.
I've been compiling this for over 45 minutes at the "Generating Code" stage.  If I set ModellingClay_00 to 10000, it compiles in about 5-10 minutes.  15000 seems to take quite a bit longer, but did eventually compile.

Is there any reason an enum should take vastly longer to compile simply from changing the value it contains?

I'm pretty sure I've run afoul of some inner voodoo of Visual Studio set aside for my personal torment.  Can anyone point out something obvious I've done, or even heard of this before?

Comment: Does something compile-time depend on the enum? For example, is there some template instantiation tied to the value of `COUNT`?

Comment: Letting the compile run overnight, I got this error:
C1128 number of sections exceeded object file format limit: compile with /bigobj 

I'm still researching what it means and what I can do, but it's a solid lead.

Comment: This further strengthens my suspicion that there's something generated based on that enumeration. If you compile a file containing just the enum's definition and nothing else, do you get the same slowness as in your original case?

Comment: Yes, Angew is correct.  Thank you.

Comment: And that is why creating a [mcve] is always a good idea.

Comment: Please pardon.  I did build a small model in a separate project, but was unable to repro in the simplest case.  I probably would have gotten it after 3-4 hours.  In the interest of expediency, I really wanted to know if I was doing something blatantly stupid.  

My initial investigation indicated possible out-of-range values (65536+), a potential limit to the number of possible elements in an enum, or that there was a bug in Visual Studio itself.  When I opened the question, It had not yet reached the end of compilation (eventually I left it overnight) to give any error message at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angew's analysis is correct.

There was a static array of VoxelTypes::COUNT elements.  Each element was 88 bytes, for a total of 5,767,168 (5.5 Mb).

My work-around was to create an array of dynamic arrays instead of using a massive table of array initializers.

Old:

```
static Elements whoppingBigTable[] = {
    {Item1, 1, 1},
    {Item2, 2, 2},
};
```

New:

```
static Elements* whoppingBigTable[64];
for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    whoppingBigTable = new Elements[1024];
}
AddElement({Item1, 1, 1});
AddElement({Item2, 2, 2});
```

Also had to add some math function to access the array elements.  I assume that this is the fastest way to do it.  It contains the definitions of my voxels, so I need to access it frequently.  (I suppose I could also define separate arrays for each voxel property, and those arrays might be small enough to compile.  That might be even faster than putting all properties into one giant array)

```
const Element& GetWhoppingElement(int index)
{
    int majorIndex = index / 1024;
    int minorIndex = index % 1024;
    return whoppingBigTable[majorIndex][minorIndex];
}
```

Comment: Nice analysis. Have an upvote. There's no harm in accepting your own answer. I'll delete mine.